Is there a synthetic approach to (symmetric) monoidal infinity-categories?
Recent work of Riehl and Verity (e.g. the book "Elements of $\infty$-category theory") has established a "synthetic" / model-independent approach to the study of $\infty$-categories, viewed as objects of an $\infty$-cosmos. Is there a similar story for (symmetric) monoidal $\infty$-categories?
More precisely, I would like to know if there's a comprehensible definition of $\mathbb{E}_k$-algebra (for $k \in \mathbb{N} \sqcup \{\infty\}$, with particular emphasis on $k = 1$ or $\infty$) in an $\infty$-cosmos which reduces to known definitions / constructions in the $\infty$-cosmos of quasicategories (or even just in the $2$-category of ordinary categories).

I don't think this stuff is really written down anywhere, but you can get at some of it relatively quickly from existing definitions, at least for the case of monoidal and symmetric monoidal ∞-categories. These should be functors out of N(Δ^{op}) and N(Fin_*) respectively satisfying a Segal condition which can be written down in any ∞-cosmos, since it's purely in terms of products and equivalences.

For ₖ-monoidal things you can do the same, you just can't use discrete categories like Δ^{op} and Fin_* to index the structure.

I'm also curious about this, but I believe Mitchell Riley's doctoral thesis "A Bunched Homotopy Type Theory for Synthetic Stable Homotopy Theory" should be relevant here.
